# Excel workout percentage change between two numbers?

Tags: excel, percentage

I have three columns:

```
January Results      Feb Results       Percentage Change
0                    11        
1                    4
10                   38
7                    12
5                    1
3                    0
```

I want to be able to work out the percentage change (increase/decrease) between my sales figures in January and February.

I am using this formula:

```
=(B2-A2)/A2
```

This works, unless i am dividing by 0, in which case it produces a #Div error.
However, if i am thinking correctly, using the example cells A2 and B2 - where there were no sales in January but were 11 sales in february, this would be a 100% increase. So instead of #Div error, I would need to get 100%.

Please can someone show me how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0 -> 11 is an infinite increase, you realise putting 100% is incorrect?

Comment: @Remuze thanks, i'm not great at math, what would be the correct logic here?

Comment: You cannot express a percentage increase from 0, as it is infinite, so you need to check if the first answer is 0, both of the answers below will fulfil your requirements, but I think Tim's suggestion of a dash in the first row is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to re-think your logic, but if you insist on it, how about

=if(a2=0,1,(B2-A2)/A2)

Format as %

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use an `IF` statement to handle this:

```
=IF(A2=0, 1, (B2-A2)/A2)
```

But as @Remuze pointed out, putting 100% for the first month technically is incorrect.  Instead, perhaps you could just put a dash:

```
=IF(A2=0, '-', (B2-A2)/A2)
```